# Android studio freezes whenever it tries to suggest method and class

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.2

Whenever I type any single letter, Android Studio tries to seek suggestion of methods and classes, and this freezes program. Even though I wait, it doesn't show any suggestions at the end whether I try to type proper method/class name or not.

I tried to check CPU usage first because whenever I try to type letters, CPU usage suddenly jumps up to about 90% from **0~10%**. I took screenshot of Activity Monitor, and total CPU usage keeps exceeding 100 whenever I try to type single letter

[image]

Plugin Kotlin takes ridiculously high CPU usage only for trying to seek suggestions. There are about 300 classes including both Java and Kotlin classes.

[image]

I set IDE max heap size as 8GB because I have 16GB RAM

[image]

I'm using Android Studio 4.2 Beta 2 version

[image]

Invalidating/Restarting caches didn't work. Removing `.idea` folder in Android project folder also didn't work.

Is there any reason for this problem? and can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that some class was causing problem, this class is java with generics. T in generic requires to extend Enum and implement my other class, this seems to cause Android Studio freeze. I'm trying to find a way to reproduce, but solved it by creating static java method which handles my codes. Only Kotlin is causing freezings.

Comment: I faced a similar issue on Android Studio 4.2 (snap) on Ubuntu. I can reproduce it only inside one (Kotlin) class with generics, when I add extra curly brace to "if" statement or remove one. If I do so, AS eat up all available memory and just freezes forever. I've tried to set Xmx to 10GB, but no luck, although usually it worked fine with 2GB! I absolutely don't understand what to do and how to avoid it. This is the first time I've encountered this in several years of work.